# Changing a list of sObjects into a JSON

Tags: apex, trigger, json, map

Having trouble with my apex code.

I have a list of objects from my trigger that I want to transform into a JSON format - can't seem to work out a way to get it going and the code I have so far is looking really complex so I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

I want a json of this format:

```
{'businesses':
{'size': 
   {'big': 
    {'coca-cola': {'color': 'red'}}, 
    {'pepsi-cola': { 'color': 'purple'}}, 
  {'small': 
    {'my-cola':{ 'color': 'green'}}
}
}
```

At the moment my code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> fourthMap = new Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>();

    for( drinks__c drink : Trigger.new){
        Map<String, String> firstMap = new Map<String, String>();
        if(drink.color__c != null){
            firstMap.put('color', drink.color__c );
        }

        String size = drink.size__c ;
        String companyName = drink.name__c;
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> secondMap = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>();
        secondMap.put(name, firstMap);
        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> thirdMap = new Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>();
        thirdMap.put('size', secondMap);
        fourthMap.put('businesses', thirdMap);
     }
    String JSONString = JSON.serialize(fourthMap);
```

First problem is that the 'big' part has been getting overwritten, second problem is that this is so complex it keeps going wrong. Any suggestions for simplifying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are not so much overwritten as they are *discarded*. You are creating a new map every time through the loop, which is causing the problem; each time you create a new map, the old map goes away. Instead, start from the top:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> businesses =
  new Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>();
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> sizes =
  new Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>();

businesses.put('businesses', sizes);

for(Drink__c drink: Trigger.new) {
  if(!sizes.containsKey(drink.size__c)) {
    sizes.put(drink.size__c, company = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>());
  }
  if(!sizes.get(drink.size__c).containsKey(drink.name__c)) {
    sizes.get(drink.size__c).put(drink.name__c, new Map<String, String>());
  }
  sizes.get(drink.size__c).get(drink.name__c).put('color',drink.color__c);
}
String jsonOutput = JSON.serialize(businesses);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you think you'll be able to understand this code after a couple of months of not working with it?

I do suggest take a different approach. First your JSON was invalid, and I fixed it as I see. Here it is

```
{
    "businesses": {
        "size": {
            "big": {
                "coca-cola": {
                    "color": "red"
                },
                "pepsi-cola": {
                    "color": "purple"
                }
            },
            "small": {
                "my-cola": {
                    "color": "green"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, try using the following class to serialize

```
public class API {
    public class RootObject {
        public BusinessesCls businesses { get; set; }
    }

    public class BusinessesCls {
        public Map<String, Map<String, BusinessCls>> size { get; set; }
    }

    public class BusinessCls {
        public string color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rename everything as you see fit. Also if you do have a fixed list of sizes I recommend using it as a `BusinessesCls` properties.
So your code for filling in an instance of the class above will look something like this:

```
RootObject obj = new RootObject();
obj.businesses = new BusinessesCls();
obj.businesses.size = new Map<String, Map<String, BusinessCls>>();
for( drinks__c drink : Trigger.new){
    BusinessCls bus = new BusinessCls();
    bus.color = drink.color__c;
    String size = drink.size__c ;
    if (!obj.businesses.size.containsKey(size)) {
        obj.businesses.size.put(size, new Map<String, BusinessCls>());
    }
    obj.businesses.size.get(size).put(drink.name__c, bus);
}
String JSONString = JSON.serialize(obj);
```